# Duplicate annotation error with SimpleXML

Tags: android, xml, simple-framework

I have the issue that I need to create XML code of a class that consists of a few primitives as well as nested classes with their values. Unfortunately, the requirement is to have two times < interface > and SimpleXML does not like that at all. How can I force SimpleXML to accept a second tag with the same name?

```
// ...
@Element(name="Interface")
public Interface Interface;
@Element(name="Interface")  // same name is an issue, but required in XML
public Interface Interface2;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the snippet below:

```
@ElementList(name="Interface", inline=true)
private List<Interface> Interface;
```